# Applying css to a text while showing in tinymce editor

Tags: php, css, xml, tinymce

I have a xml file with content

```
<ul>
 <li><info>Some text here</info></li>
</ul>
```

I have parsed the xml file and show this in a page.`info` is a css class.In the page the text showing with css.When i am editing the content in tinymce editor how i can apply the css in the editor.In the editor the text is showing like `<div mce_name="info">CSS text formatting </div>`Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to apply the css to the text actually entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the styles to the tinymce style sheet, they should appear in 'styles' the drop down.